# Windows 8 restore

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, system-restore, carbonite

I currently run Windows 7 on my laptop, but it is on the way out and need to purchase a new one.  Can I purchase a Windows 8 machine and know that Carbonite will successfully do a full system restore to my new laptop.  In other words, if the backup is from a windows 7 machine, will I be able to do a full restore to a windows 8 machine?

Comment: What do you mean by full system restore? Carbonite AFAIK doesn't do complete system imaging. As for whatever files it does backup (from automatically included and manually specified locations), you can always select what you want to restore. Finally, since you're paying for it, why not use the Support option? Get what you're paying for, which includes Support.

Comment: Agreed, system imaging was probably not the correct terminology.  I just wondered if there was support for restoring everything that is backed up from Windows 7 to Windows 8.  By the way, I still do not know.

Comment: Well, you install the app and restore your files. I don't see what could stop you from doing so, unless you manually backed up system files that are being used by the OS you're restoring to.